# Adding value from html page on database

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I use Microsoft Visual Studio and Microsoft sql server 2008. I create web site and I want to add text value which user enter information on sql table. I use Nhibarnate and FluentNhibernate. But my code can not add value. I create map , entity and how can I add value from web page text. What can I do for this problem?

**table**

```
  |Address table|
    --------------
    |AddressId     | int
    ------------------------
    |FullName      | varchar
    ------------------------
    |AddressLine1  | varchar
    ------------------------ 
    |AddressLine2  | varchar 
    ------------------------
    |city          | varchar
    ------------------------
    |State         | varchar
    ------------------------
    |zip           | varchar
    ------------------------
    |country       | varchar
    ------------------------
```

FluentlyConfig.cs

```
namespace Deneme.Config
{
    public class FluentlyConfig
    {
        private static readonly log4net.ILog logger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
        private ISessionFactory SessionFactory { get; set; }

        private FluentlyConfig()
        {
            SessionFactory = CreateSessionFactory();
        }

        public static FluentlyConfig Instance
        {
            get
            {
                return FluentNhibernateConfigFactory.instance;
            }
        }

        public class FluentNhibernateConfigFactory
        {
            static FluentNhibernateConfigFactory() { }
            internal static readonly FluentlyConfig instance = new FluentlyConfig();
        }

        public ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
        {
            try
            {
                if (this.SessionFactory == null)
                {
                    return Fluently.Configure()
                    .Database(
                    MsSqlConfiguration
                    .MsSql2008
                    .ConnectionString(c => c
                    .FromConnectionStringWithKey("DB"))
                    .DefaultSchema("dbo")
                    )
                    .Mappings(m =>
                    {
                        m.FluentMappings
                        .AddFromAssemblyOf<Address>()
                       .Conventions.Add(FluentNHibernate.Conventions.Helpers.DefaultLazy.Never());
                    })
                    .BuildSessionFactory();
                }
                else { return SessionFactory; }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.Fatal("Bağlantı Oluşturulamadı", ex);
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Deneme.Controllers
{
    public class Default1Controller : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Default1/

        public ActionResult Index()
        { 
            return View();
        }
        public JsonResult deneme( String AddressId, String FullName, String AddressLine1 ,String  AddressLine2 ,String City ,String State, String Zip ,String Country )
        {
        return new JsonResult();           
        }

    }
}
```

**Entities**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Deneme.Entities
{
    public class Address
    {
    public virtual int AddressId {get; set;}
    public virtual string FullName {get; set;}
    public virtual string AddressLine1 {get; set;}
    public virtual string AddressLine2 {get; set;}
    public virtual string City {get; set;}
    public virtual string State {get; set;}
    public virtual string Zip {get; set;}
    public virtual string Country {get; set;}

//AddressId FullName AddressLine1 AddressLine2 City State Zip Country
    }
}
```

**Mapping**

```
using Deneme.Entities;
using FluentNHibernate.Mapping;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Deneme.Mapping
{
    public class AddressMap : ClassMap<Address>
    {
        public AddressMap()
        {
            Table("Address");
            Id(x => x.AddressId).Column("Id").GeneratedBy.Identity();
            Map(x => x.FullName).Column("Fullname");
            Map(x => x.AddressLine1).Column("AddressLine1");
            Map(x => x.AddressLine2).Column("AddressLine2");
            Map(x => x.City).Column("City");
            Map(x => x.State).Column("State");
            Map(x => x.Zip).Column("Zip");
            Map(x => x.Country).Column("Country");
        }  
    }
}
```

**Index.cshtml text part and js part. I want to send value after click button**

**button**

```
 <p><a href="button1" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Send &raquo;</a></p>
```

**Address Form Part**

### Address

```
        <!-- full-name input-->
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Full Name</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input id="full-name" name="full-name" type="text" placeholder="full name"
                class="input-xlarge">
                <p class="help-block"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- address-line1 input-->
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Address Line 1</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input id="address-line1" name="address-line1" type="text" placeholder="address line 1"
                class="input-xlarge">
                <p class="help-block">Street address, P.O. box, company name, c/o</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- address-line2 input-->
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Address Line 2</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input id="address-line2" name="address-line2" type="text" placeholder="address line 2"
                class="input-xlarge">
                <p class="help-block">Apartment, suite , unit, building, floor, etc.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- city input-->
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">City / Town</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input id="city" name="city" type="text" placeholder="city" class="input-xlarge">
                <p class="help-block"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- region input-->
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">State / Province / Region</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input id="region" name="region" type="text" placeholder="state / province / region"
                class="input-xlarge">
                <p class="help-block"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- postal-code input-->
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Zip / Postal Code</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input id="postal-code" name="postal-code" type="text" placeholder="zip or postal code"
                class="input-xlarge">
                <p class="help-block"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- country select -->
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Country</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <select id="country" name="country" class="input-xlarge">
                    <option value="" selected="selected">(please select a country)</option>
                    <option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
                    <option value="AL">Albania</option>
                    <option value="DZ">Algeria</option>
                    <option value="AS">American Samoa</option>
                    <option value="AD">Andorra</option>
                    <option value="AO">Angola</option>
                    <option value="AI">Anguilla</option>
                    <option value="AQ">Antarctica</option>
                    <option value="AG">Antigua and Barbuda</option>
                    <option value="AR">Argentina</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**java script part**

```
@section jscript
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#button1").live("click", function () {
             $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: path + "Default1/deneme",
                    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                    data: "{FullName:\"" + $("#full-name").val() +
                         "}",
                    data: "{AddressLine1:\"" + $("#address-line1").val() +
                           "}",
                    data: "{AddressLine2:\"" + $("#address-line2").val() +
                            "}",
                    data: "{ City:\"" + $("#city").val() +
                            "}",
                    data: "{State:\"" + $("#region").val() +
                            "}",
                    data: "{Zip:\"" + $("#postal-code").val() +
                            "}",
                    data: "{Country:\"" + $("#country").val() +
                            "}",

                    success: function (data) {


                    },
                    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        $("#button1").removeAttr("disabled");
                        alert(thrownError);
                    }
                });

        });
    </script>
}
```

**AND the last  Web.config. I do data base and w.studio connection at this part.**

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DB" connectionString="server=A88;uid=ABC;pwd=123;database=DS"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

**Action.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Deneme.Entities;

namespace Deneme
{
    public class Actions
    {
        public bool SaveData(string AddressId, string FullName, string AddressLine1, string AddressLine2, string City, string State, string Zip, string Country)
        {
            Address adress = new Address();

            adress.City= City;
            adress.AddressLine1 = AddressLine1;
            adress.AddressLine2 = AddressLine2;
            adress.Country = Country;
            adress.FullName = FullName;
            adress.State = State;
            adress.Zip = Zip;
             return true;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you opening the session and adding address to the session?

Comment: also, where do you call SaveData ?

Comment: ı want to call at class Default1Controller. But ı can not do algorithm ı think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer in its simplistic form is to open a session, begin a transaction then commit. Something along the lines of:-

```
public bool SaveData(...)
{
  using (var session = Deneme.Config.FluentlyConfigure.SessionFactory.OpenSession())
  {
    using (var tran = session.BeginTransaction())
    {
      Address adress = new Address();
      adress.City= City;
      ...
      session.Save(address);
      tran.commit();
    }
  }

  return true;
}
```

It looks like you might need to refactor your `FluentlyConfig` class to expose the `SessionFactory`. You might want to look at [sesion-per-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/session-per-request) to help you for session management in NHibernate.

Also I would check your AJAX POST as that does look right as well.

Comment: ı add this code at ACtion but session not define said and what is "NAMESPACE HER"E ?

Comment: that is the namespace that contains your `SessionFactory` class. Something like `Deneme.Config.FluentlyConfigure.` However as I pointed out the SessionFactory property is marked as PRIVATE.

Comment: sorry my stupid question this my first app. But what can ı write at Namsespace ?  ı do not understand

Comment: Edited, however for your first app you really are doing some complex stuff. I suggest learning the basics of C# first!

Comment: can ı asked question ? at --public JsonResult deneme( String AddressId, String FullName, String AddressLine1 ,String  AddressLine2 ,String City ,String State, String Zip ,String Country )
        {
        return new JsonResult();" is String City have to text name or cloumn name?

Comment: Sorry I am not 100% sure what you are asking. Are you saying you want to validate the model before saving? If so then I would ask another question here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36013/discussion-between-ad-ku-and-rippo)

Answer (score 0):

Straight away I can see that your AJAX call is completelly wrong. You only pass in one `data` object.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: path + "Default1/deneme",
    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
    data: { 
        FullName: "", 
        AddressLine1: "", 
        AddressLine2: "", 
        City: "", 
        State: "", 
        Zip: "", 
        Country: ""
    },
    success: function (data) {

    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        $("#button1").removeAttr("disabled");
        alert(thrownError);
    }
});
```

You will then need to hook up your `JsonResult` `deneme` to the rest of your code.

Comment: but ı think it is same. at one data or more data.. it is choice if ı am wrong please fix me. And ı want to after click button. How can ı hook up ? I do not understand sorry me easy question but this my first app